# Routine doctor visit for people with myopia?

Tags: eye, prevention

Should people with myopia (short-sightedness) who otherwise show no symptoms of eye problems and wear corrective lenses visit an eye doctor (whether optometrist or ophthalmologist - my country doesn't even have that distinction)? If they should, are there any recommendations as to how often these visits should happen and what exams need to be scheduled?

Answer (score 2):

This probably varies from country to country. In mine (France), it is recommended to see an ophtalmologist (we have the distinction here) every three years for non-severe myopia, because your sight can vary a bit during that time. For children it's every year because children's sight vary much more than ours. For severe myopia, the ophtalmologist decides what schedule will be best - often every year as well.

The tests are generally eyesight measurements (for myopia, far-sightedness and astigmatism). Sometimes, especially in older people, you'll get a fundus examination as well.

[This site](http://eyewiki.aao.org/Myopia) has description of myopia progression that justifies the regular checks in the classification part.

Comment: I think we actually only have ophthalmologist here in Germany. So I can put this answer into context: Are eyesight measurements only done by doctors in France? I ask because I have never seen a doctor for that and thus think it's strange to go see a doctor "just" for that.

Comment: @YviDe It's probably a cultural thing, what is medical and what is paramedical varies a lot according to where you live. Optometrists exist here (although they're very rare) but they aren't recognized so, like opticians, they can do eyesight measurements but you won't get reimbursed by social security if you don't have a prescription (which is only valid 3 years) from an ophthalmologist . So in practice you go to the doctor, get your prescription, go to the optician who will often adjust it, and then you have your glasses/lenses. This could change in the years to come, however.